# Converting a classification raster to a polygon, in order to calculate the area of each land use

Tags: raster, polygon, area

I have 6 land use categories. ultimately I would like to calculate the area of all of the classification categories in my layer e.g. the area of the deforestation, or the area of primary forest. I am trying to convert it from a raster to a polygon, in order to calculate the area from the attribute table. however when using the raster to polygon tool it is not working. I input the classified raster, leave VALUE as it is, then select an output in a new folder, tick SIMPLIFY POLYGON and 3 times it has not worked. I have looked at online tutorials and followed exactly what they do, and mine still does not work. Any suggestions please on what may be wrong?

Comment: In whatever software you are working in it should be trivial to retrieve the pixel counts for each class and, you know what the cell size is. So, why are you adding the complication of converting to polygon just to get class areas?

Comment: I have since realised this, thank you. However, my area and pixel count of deforested land is larger in 1988 than 2010, which does not make sense. This is because the pixels from the background of the image are being incorporated, skewing the data. If you have any ideas how to amend this, that would be very useful. I have tried copying the raster and changing the background value to 0, but this doesnt seem to work for the supervised classification raster created. It still has a background, even when the mosaic image has it removed.

Comment: This is why it is good to indicate what software you are working with. Your problem is procedural in nature and not an issue with the data. All you have to do is have a mask, indicating the study area, to set the background to 0 and everything outside the study area to nodata. Depending on the software, the approach is slightly different but quite easily accomplished using mask or con type statements. In practice, one wants to avoid converting rasters to polygons. You can likely do this by simply using a mask. Unless you have a reason for 0 values you want to set the background to NA.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I am working in ArcMap. A mask sounds like a good idea, although I am unsure how to go about this. Do I need to mask every output I create, or do I just apply a mask to my initial mosaic image?

Comment: In your environment settings, you can define a mask. Any resulting raster calculations will then be limited to said limits. I should note that an extent is rectangular in nature whereas a mask can let you specify an irregular area where everything outside is returned as nodata.